# Перевести несколько строчек кода из Паскаля в Питон

Tags: python, pascal

Имеется строчка кода в Паскале

```
if f(x)>x+3 then inc(k)
```

Как она будет выглядеть в питоне?
Нужно,чтобы конечный код показывал  кол-во точек,расположенных выше прямой y=x+3

Вот код,который я написал в Питоне

```
from math import *
print("Введите исходные данные")
print("x0 = ", end='')
x0 = float(input())
print("xs = ", end='')
xs = float(input())
print("x2 = ", end='')
x2 = float(input())
print("Вы ввели:")
print("x0 = %.1f  xs = %.1f  x2 = %.1f" % (x0, xs, x2))
k = 0 
x = x0
y = 0
while x <= x2 + xs / 2:
    y = 3*(x**2)+2*x+1
    if y > (x+3):
```

И вот что делать после последней строчки я не знаю

Comment: Если проблема только в `inc`, то это `k = k + 1`.

Comment: @AlexR. Огромное спасибо :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если проблема только в `inc`, то это `k = k + 1`.

*inc* это сокращение от слова *increment* - прирастить.